# Why a boolean can be in some cases converted to a string, and in other cases not?

Tags: java, string, boolean

I used a method that took a `String` and I wanted to pass a primitive `boolean`. I expect it to take that `boolean` and convert it to a String containing either "true" or "false".

Assume the following method:

```
public void method(String input) { ... }
```

I first tried something like this:

```
boolean myBoolean = true;
method(myBoolean.toString());
```

This gave me an error during compilation. But then when I added following additional overloaded method, this worked again:

```
public void method(Boolean input) {
   method(input);
}
```

I was confused to discover that in that case, calling `method(myBoolean)` worked just fine.

Why is this?

Comment: what error? share your code......

Comment: It sounds like you're using a `boolean`, which is the data type, and not a `Boolean`, which is the encapsulating object. You can't use methods on primitive data types. Java magic would turn the primitive `boolean` into a `String` for the method invocation.

Comment: @JunedAhsan `Cannot invoke toString() on the primitive type boolean`, because that method doesn't exist for booleans. Why do you need my code? I just want to know why `boolean`s can be passed to a method which takes a `string` as an argument

Comment: @AntonH yes primitive `boolean`

Comment: @Aequitas It can't, but you seem to have used the `Boolean` (as a guess) Object's `toString` method to make into a `String`.  There is a difference between `boolean` and `Boolean`, although with autoboxing, a lot of the headaches have gone away

Comment: @MadProgrammer no capital B `Boolean`, just the lower case one. I'm asking why a `boolean` can be passed into a method that takes a `string`. Sorry I am not being very clear. The `toString` method did not compile, because it was a boolean so I removed it, but it worked as a boolean which is confusing to me

Comment: @Aequitas This is why an example of what you are doing which demonstrates your problem is helpful ;)

Comment: @Aequitas - The short answer is _It can't_ . If a method takes a `String` then you cannot pass a `boolean` (or `Boolean`) to it. The reason everyone wants to see your code is to try and understand what is actually going on, so we can explain the apparent confusion - because what you have described is impossible.

Comment: My apologies everyone, it seems I'm an idiot. Apparently there was an overload method that would take the boolean. Massive derp haha. Like how sysout(`string`) but you can also sysout(`boolean`)

Comment: @Aequitas better perform a derp-search before posting a question next time

Comment: @MCMastery yeh haha, sorry, I derped so hard, I feel like an idiot now :(

Comment: Instead of `myBoolean.toString()` (which won't work for primitive `boolean` types), try `String.valueOf(myBoolean)`.

Comment: This got downvoted, but seems a *terrific* question for someone new to Java; giving you an upvote if only just to balance the downvote I see now.  The issue is the difference between primatives and Objects, and the autoboxing feature that will put your primatives into an object under certain circumstances.

Comment: @DeanJ agree. I am not new to Java - and still I learned something out of it, as I had to try and research the problem first. Avoids me being the know-it-all (well - maybe I just edged a little closer to being just that :-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primitive types (`boolean` for example) do not have methods. That is why an error occured when you tried boolean.toString(). Wrapper classes than though (`Boolean.toString()` for example).

Now for the method, if your method is like this:

```
public void method(String s)
```

then you must have made another method like this:

```
public void method(boolean b)
```

to be able to perform method(boolean). Without the method(boolean b), your compiler would say `method cannot be applied to boolean` or something along those lines.

Comment: It didn't throw an exception.

Answer (score 3):

First thing to understand is that primitives do not have methods. At least not as of date, and might change with implementation of [Project Valhalla](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/valhalla/). To be able to call the `toString()` on it, you will first require to box it either by [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) or by wrapping it explicitly.

Given a method `public void takeString(String input) {}`:

1. `takeString(true)` will fail, although
2. `takeString(""+true)` will work, as it is equivalent to
3. `takeString(""+Boolean.valueOf(true).toString())`, which works.
4. `takeString(Boolean.valueOf(true).toString())` will work as well, but note that
5. `takeString(Boolean.valueOf(true))` will fail again for the same reason as in (1).

It might be curious that in case (2), it was able to apply [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) and implicitly call the `toString()`, while it was not able to do so for (1).

But there is good reason for it, as in the case of (2), it is clear to the compiler that the method signature will have a parameter type of `String`, so it can do the needed implicit conversions. While for (1), it would be dangerous to do so given that we can have multiple overloaded versions of `takeString`. It just makes the compiler's job simpler, and avoids issues when the overloaded version would be added later on. It is safer to fail on (2).

Example, we do not want logic to suddenly change because we add following method: `public void takeString(boolean input) {}`.

Possibly you could consider adding following method:

```
public void takeString(Boolean b) {
  takeString(b.toString());
}
```

The intent of "conversion-only" is clear here, and will reduce the chance of adding in additional unintended logic.

In that case, it might also be wiser to provide an overloaded version for the native `boolean` parameter to avoid surprises later on as the API evolves.

Then all your cases, except `true.toString()` will work. Seems like a case to ask to implement conversions in Java, the way we have them in Scala. That will avoid a lot of overload boilerplate.

Comment: This is a really good answer.  The one bit it may be missing is Autoboxing, a feature of Java, documented here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Comment: @DeanJ incorporated it in the answer. Thanks.